# How does $\text d/\text dx (\ln(1/x) + c) = \text d/\text dx (c -\ln(x))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the derivative of the following expression 
$\ln\left(\frac 1 x\right) + c$

it appears the answer is $-\frac 1 x$

however i am told it can be the original expression can be simplified to 
$c - \ln(x)$

i am wondering how this is possible

Comment: ln(1/x) = -ln(x)

Answer (score 1):

Because $\log a^b = b \log a$, so:
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \ln \left( x^{-1} \right) = -\ln x$$
See: [logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations).